# LeetCode sort color java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to use ArrayList to sort the nums[] but it can only pass 17/83 cases. I don't know where I did wrong.

```
public class Solution {
   public void sortColors(int[] nums) {
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Integer> redList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Integer> whiteList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Integer> blueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       if(nums==null||nums.length==0)
          return ;

       for(int number:nums){
           switch (number){
               case 0:
                  redList.add(number);
                  break;
               case 1:
                  whiteList.add(number);
                  break;
               case 2:
                  blueList.add(number);
                  break;
               default:
                  break;
           }
       }
       list.addAll(redList);
       list.addAll(whiteList);
       list.addAll(blueList);
   }
}
```

It tooks a lot of extra space, but i think it's can be faster than insertion sort.

Comment: what you want to do? i don't understand you...

Comment: you have 3 lists, for example {0, 0, 0}, {1,1,1}, {2,2,2} and what then?

Comment: @AndrewTobilkosorry, I forgot post the question. Given an array with n objects colored red, white or blue, sort them so that objects of the same color are adjacent, with the colors in the order red, white and blue.

Here, we will use the integers 0, 1, and 2 to represent the color red, white, and blue respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the API due [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Must be Integer class
    Integer[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0,
            0, 4 };

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(nums);
    // Before sort
    System.out.println("Before sort :" + list.toString());

    // Sort 'list' items
    Collections.sort(list);
    // After sort
    System.out.println("After sort :" + list.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
Before sort :[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
After sort :[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sort Colors problems approach in 3 steps**

### Approach

1. initalize low=0,mid=0 and high=nums.length-1;
2. check nums[mid] with nums[low] , also nums[mid] with nums[high]
3. perform operation after comparison as show in switch cases.

```
class Solution {
    public void sortColors(int[] nums) {
        if(nums.length==1){
            return;
        }
        int low=0,mid=0,high=nums.length-1;
        while(mid<=high){
            switch(nums[mid]){
                case 0:
                    int temp=nums[low];
                    nums[low]=nums[mid];
                    nums[mid]=temp;
                    mid++;
                    low++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mid++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    int temp1=nums[mid];
                    nums[mid]=nums[high];
                    nums[high]=temp1;
                    high--;
                    break;
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should not use the built-in functions while practicing algorithms :)

The algorithm they have asked is a standard one called `3-way-quicksort` or `national-flag-sort` or `two-pivot-sort`. Very nice explanation is in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-quicksort-dutch-national-flag/

The point is to have two pivots and basically you would be able to sort array inplace in single iteration.

```
Space complexity: O(1) (no extra space)
Time comlexity: O(n)
```